# devcon on windows 7 - remove drivers

Tags: scripting, windows-7, batch-file

I have a problem using `devcon.exe` in Windows 7 for the purpose of removing drivers, it worked fine in Windows XP. However, I can't remove the drivers using "dp_delete" and "Remove" in Windows 7.

Anyone has an idea why it might happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download the “Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 7.1.0″ from MS, it is an ISO image several hundreds meg
2. Using UniversalExtractor (http://legroom.net/software/uniextract), extract the ISO to a temporary directory.
3. Again using UniversalExtractor, extract the install file "WDK\setuptools_x64fre.msi" to a temporary directory.
4. In that temporary directory you will find "WinDDK\7600.16385.win7_wdk.100208-1538\tools\devcon\amd64\devcon.exe". This devcon works fine under W7x64 Pro.

Along the way UniversalExtractor will prompt you with some warnings, just click OK.

([source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/devcon-not-working-correctly-in-windows-7/9abcc12c-d7db-4249-aec4-fc4ff0ea6ee8))

Comment: it doesn't work. i get a windows with a checkbox, if i mark that i want to remove the driver, it removes it, but i want it to operate without user input, meaning, automaticly

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue. `C:\Users\Stijn\Downloads>devcon dp_delete oem18.inf`
`Driver package 'oem18.inf' deleted.`

Comment: perhaps i'm using the wron eom? is there a way to check which oem represents my driver? can i get a list of drivers and their oem's?

Comment: You can get a list with the command `devcon dp_enum`. For more commands, see `devcon help`.

Comment: `devcon dp_delete <.inf>` doesn't work even with `-f` option. The link in the answer is outdated and reported as dangerous.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I've removed the link. I can't comment on the other issue, since this was quite a long time ago and I don't remember the details.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea for another one that have the same issue and can migrate it: you can use wmic instead devcon. Its work better and it's Query Oriented Language (WMI)